# Does Boto retry on failed md5 checks?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

The boto config has a `num_retries` parameter for uploads.

> **num_retries**
>
> The number of times to retry failed requests to an AWS server. If boto
>   receives an error from AWS, it will attempt to recover and retry the
>   request. The default number of retries is 5 but you can change the
>   default with this option.

My understanding is that this parameter governs how many times to retry on commands like `set_content_from_string`. According to the documentation, the same command will fail if the md5 checksum does not match upon upload. My question is, will boto also retry upon checksum failure, or does `num_retry` apply to a separate class of failures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When boto uploads a file to S3 it calculates the MD5 checksum locally, sends that checksum to S3 as the `Content-MD5` header and then checks the value of the `ETag` header returned by the S3 service against the previously computed MD5 checksum.  If the `ETag` header does not match the MD5 it raises an `S3DataError` exception.  This exception is a subclass of `ClientError` and client errors are not retried by boto.

It is also possible for the S3 service to return a `BadDigest` error if the `Content-MD5` header we provide does not match the MD5 checksum computed by the service.  This is a 400 response from S3 and is also considered a client error and would not be retried.